# Categorizing output from an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, output, slice

I am having some difficulty in categorizing an output from an array in bash. I extracted two items from a zoo of xmls (animalType and pedigreeID). Then I created an array that looks like this:

```
giraffe 1625327, 
rhino 1356097, 
rhino 1356103, 
rhino 1356107, 
lion 1412753, 
lion 1412756, 
lion 1412761, 
elephant 1596343, 
elephant 1596421, 
deer 1225610
```

Each value in the array is made of an animalType and a pedigreeID. What I am trying to output and insert in another larger script his this:

for giraffe I have these IDs: `1625327`
for rhino I have these IDs: `1356097, 1356103, 1356107` 
for lion I have these IDs: 1`412753, 1412756, 1412761`
for elephant I have these IDs: `1596343, 1596421` 
for deer I have these IDs: `1225610`

With this I make a document called by the name of the animalType and inside I have the list of pedigreeIDs. One document for each animalType. Then another script reads these files and process them.

I started to write code for the first part but realized that I didn't know enough about arrays and making the type of lists I needed. I looked on the net for various ways but couldn't find something that matched my scenario. I need to learn how to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#array created from xml files
myarray=( $(cat *.xml | grep -e animalType -e pedigreeID | sed  's/<animalType>//g;s/<\/animalType>//g;s/<pedigreeID>//g;s/<\/pedigree ID>//g' | sed 'N;s/\n//' | gawk '{print $2, $1}' | sort ))

Declare -A seen
for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    if [ ! "${seen[$i]}" ]; then 
       result+=("$i")
       seen[$i]=1
    fi
done
echo "${result[@]}"
```

This gives me a list of animalType with the pedigreeIDs following. Not what I need. I tried other ways but could get it. I would appreciate any hint on resolving this. Hopefully, I have given enough data.

Comment: It would be helpful to show a minimal example of the source XML, and your desired output. Parsing XML with regular expressions is not recommended -- use an XML parser.

Comment: (agree with all above) AND if you really must do this, then check your code at https://shellcheck.net as I see several typos. You can most likely reduce the `cat file | grep | sed | send | gawk` pipeline to `awk '{code}' file` . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Getting the two lines from the XMLs is not the issue. What I am trying to resolve is how to categorize the data from "myarray." Getting the list of animals and their pedigreeID is working fine. I have different ways of collecting this information. Categorizing this data by animalType is where I bug. Sorry if there are typos. I just retyped a sample of my code on the fly.

Comment: The desired output is a text file for each animalType and their pedigreeID listed inside the file. File name would "elephant.txt" and inside there would be a simple list of IDs, such as 1596343 1596421 1596523. The IDs would be one per line. I will post a sample if I can figure out how to link a file.

Comment: Thank you Shellter. Nice Code checker at shellcheck.net. I handled the typos.

Comment: Will help to post sample output for the input that you described.

Comment: Shell scripts aren't for processing data; they are for running other programs that process data. Use a language with proper data structures (and a proper XML parsing library).

Comment: put that 2 column list in a file and then `while read type pedigree ; do echo "$pedigree" >> "$type" ; done < 2colList.txt`. Arrays are cool, but often overkill in shell processing.  Note that each time you run this script, data will be appended to exisiting `type` files, so you'll need to delete them before you run the script again. Good luck.

Comment: shellter < thank you very much. With a couple of tweaks I almost get what I need. I am able to create a file name for each animalType, but the pedigree (second column) write the word "pedigree" for each instance. It does not pick up the pedigree number. In the example above, I got 5 files called giraffe, rhino, lion, elephant and deer. What I am trying to get inside  these files is the pedigree number listed in each file. I am going to try a few variations, but if you've got some idea, please let me know. Again, thanks for helping.

Comment: Shellter < it actually works! I had missed the "$" in front of pedigree. I am pumped. Could you explain how $pedigree can pick up the second column of the file 2colList.txt. Also, how do I accept your answer.

Comment: Glad that helped. The trick  I am using is the `while read line ; do echo $line ; done < inputFile` . Here each line of data (all fields) is stored as `$line`. But, you can tell `read` to read in `N` variables (any number, per line), you just have to name them, in your case `read type pedigree`, reads 2 variables from each line of data. Maybe someone else will want to write up a complete answer which you can accept. But feel free to upvote [one of my low vote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter?tab=answers)  ;-) .

Comment: I didn't mention it before, but if you're going to be processing this sort of data and can't afford (or otherwise use) a database, then you'll do well to learn some `awk` coding. While not a perfect tutorial, [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) is pretty good and worth your time. Good luck.

Comment: [Handful of awk one-liners](https://jetlib.com/unix_tips/awktips.html) will give you a good intro to basic awk stuff. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I learned something today. Grymoire has always been my go to site to learn about Unix commands. Even though I used gawk a little bit in my scripts, I never read his whole write-up. Will do so now. I didn't know you could tell read to read in N variables. This is extremely useful for many of my scripts. I did some upvotes, but because I signed recently, it said that the upvotes are recorded but not displayed. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Another person I want to thanks even though he didn't continue on this treads is Glenn Jackman. I have read many of his posts in the past when I needed to put some bash scripts together, especially about Parallel and Expect. I am not a programmer but do write batch scripts on Linux.